# codeigniter with flexgrid

Tags: codeigniter, flexigrid

I have just downloaded the flexigrid and examples and tried to execute. In the example, there is a function getCountries, which populates the grid with countries from the database…

I tried this and it seems the flexigrid just keeps processing (it says processing and turns and turns)...

Am i doing anything wrong.

ThanX

Comment: what response are you getting from the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. including prototype.js created the problem. After removing that, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you should look at [jQuery.noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) if you want to include prototype